# Material Design on gingerbread

Tags: android, material-design

Can someone help me understand why my dialog looks fine-ish on lollipop and kitkat, but is horrible on Gingerbread?  Image below lollipop left, gingerbread right (obviously).

I am on the latest version of appcompat as well.[image]

Comment: not so horrible. apparently you only lack the backgrounds

Comment: Have you set styles properly, ie. in your manifest and `styles.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default implementation of dialogs which change drastically between Android versions.

Use a library like https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs to achieve a common design between all api levels.

Or you can do this yourself by messing around with backgrounds and such.